# google fonts not working in c9.io IDE

Tags: html, google-font-api

I added fonts in between  tags :

```
<link href='Felipa-Regular.ttf' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Felipa' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

In all hosting this working fine but in c9.io IDE not work, maybe someone know any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first `link` element. It tries to refer to a font file as a CSS file, and this won’t work.

The second `link` element is correct, but it only makes the Felipa font available. It does not make any element actually use it. You need to add code like

```
<style>
* { font-family: Felipa; }
</style>
```

If you still have problems with some hosting service (which is what “c9.io IDE” seems to refer to), consult the instructions given by the service provider.